# Replace dictionary values according to dictionary

Tags: python, performance, parsing, dictionary

I have two dictionaries. 
One contains data in the following way `d['name']=[something,{attribute:placeholder}]`
So a dictionary containing a list (not an array, as I originally stated) containing a dictionary, where the values are placeholder letter combinations and not unique.

The other dict contains `s['placeholder']=value`

I want to replace all the placeholders in d with their corresponding values in s.

Is there any way I can do this efficiently and not by looping through the s dict for every entry in the d attributes?

Comment: There are no arrays in pure python. What you got there is a simple list with a dictionary inside.

Comment: @ascenator: actually, [there are](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html). But the OP is indeed not using them, they have `list` objects here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, but is it really an array? A class with things like append and stuff sounds to me like just another python wrapper object. Or is it really using an array inside and doing things like creating a new array with a higher capacity and copying the values from the old array when using methods like append? Has it O(1) when accessing any single value?

Comment: @ascenator: The Python `list` type uses a dynamic C array underneath. You didn't qualify what you understand to be an array, however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: A data structure consisting of elements with the same (primitive) data type, fixed in capacity because the underlying memory is allocated exactly once and therefore the values are lying sequential in the memory granting an access of O(1) for every value.

Comment: @ascenator: Python `list` and `array` objects offer O(1) access to all elements. They are dynamically managed, so appending can trigger a copy operation. The cost is amortised however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you'll have to loop. you can use a dictionary comprehension here:

```
d = {name: [v[0], {attr: s[placeholder] for attr, placeholder in v[1].items()}]
     for name, v in d.items()}
```

This rebuilds the whole structure, with the values in the nested dictionaries replaced by mapping the placeholders through `s`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain, what exactly is happening here?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) and [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries); the `{key: value for ...}` expression builds a dictionary from a loop. I just nested the technique to build the value of the outer dictionary.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I am getting the idea.
I need to do it unnested though, as there can be multiple values or none at all. 
Anyhow, thank you, question solved!